# Passing and using a value from another method

Tags: django, django-views

In my view.py;

```
def get_social_data(request):
    author_name = request.GET.get('author')
    // To do something
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type='application/json')
```

In the same view.py but in different function, I need to use author_name. If I again write `"author_name = request.GET.get('author')"`, it returns "NONE".

```
def profile_export(request, slug):
     author_name = request.GET.get('author') // Now NONE.
```

Can you help me how to pass the value to profile_export() from get_social_data(). Or is there any other way to get author_name?

Thank you.

Comment: However I do not want to call profile_export into get_social_data because these views are called by clicking different buttons. get_social_data is called to see the profile of a user. However, profile_export() enables a user to export all information of that user into an Excel file.

Comment: You don't, a view is a return to a request. You pass the author as a get parameter

Comment: Each call to a view is a different request. If you want to get parameters from a request in a view, you need to actually have those parameters in the request.

Comment: If is the same `author` you can save it in a `session` in the first function and then use it from the `session` in the second function.

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I need @doru . Thank you it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is the same `author` you can save it in a django [`session`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/) in the first function and then use it from the `session` in the second function.

```
def get_social_data(request):
    author_name = request.GET.get('author')
    session['author_name'] = author_name
    .....
```

And in the second function;

```
def profile_export(request, slug):
    author_name = session['author_name']
```