# Django Render several attributes at the same time?

Tags: python, django

How to render several calculations created by different functions from different views at the same time on the same template?

Comment: Can you describe some more your question?

Comment: Show us your code of different views you are talking about ?

Comment: class Index_one(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    template_name = "dashboard.html"

    def get(self, request): 
        context = Table.attribute
        return render(request, self.template_name,context )

Comment: I would like couple of functions like these always be on one template when user logs in

Comment: As far as I understand from your question a little bit, I think what you are trying to is not possible because a view returns a request. You want to make calculations in a view and pass the variable to other view methods. However it is possible to calculate them and render these parametres and html file and use them into that html file.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a little bit similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914628/passing-and-using-a-value-from-another-method) like this before and here it is the answer. However, after a while, I understand that session is not a good way to pass parameter from one view to another.